# Entity Framework Database First: connect to a particular database schema in runtime mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

We were recommended (by Microsoft specialists) to use database schemas inside a single db instead of separate databases for each customer of our service. 
We are currently using Database first approach.

User story: when I log in as a guy from company 1, on page "warehouses I get info from table u1.Warehouses. Company 2 - u2.Warehouses and so on.

Question: by having schema name for a particular user, how can we establish connection to that_schema_name.Table_name in runtime mode using Entity Framework?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the user that is logged and his membership to roles, company, or whatever you define in your application, you can conditionally set the schema. Bellow I provided the sample with **If** control flow construction and *IsInRole* method from *CurrentPrincipal*, obviously it may not be your final solution but should put you in track :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    if ( Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Foo") )
       modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("that_schema_name");
    else
       modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("other_schema_name");   

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! We've tried it already. But OnModelCreating method seems to be used in CodeFirst approach only, we've got DatabaseFirst.

Comment: That is not correct. You can use OnModelCreating with DatabaseFirst too.

Comment: We have tried your solution once again. Unfortunately, event handler not called :(

Comment: OnModelCreating is not a handler, it is a virtual method from DbContext. Post your code you have for this class.